# Debug cgi script on the command line with json

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a cgi script that gets sent some simple json, and I want to parse the json, then return a couple of the values.  I'm trying to test my cgi script on the command line, but I get this error:

> malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or
>   atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at
>   1.pl line 21.

Here's my command line attempt:

```
$ perl 1.pl '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
<h1>Software error:</h1>
<pre>malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before &quot;(end of string)&quot;) at 1.pl line 21.
</pre>
<p>
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message 
and the time and date of the error.

</p>
[timestamp] 1.pl: malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at 1.pl
```

1.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use JSON;

my $q = CGI->new;

my $json = $q->param('POSTDATA');
my $href = decode_json($json);
my $a = $href->{a};
my $b = $href->{b};

print $q->header,
      $q->start_html("Test Page"),
      $q->h1("Results:"),
      $q->div("a=$a"),
      $q->div("b=$b"),
      $q->end_html;
```

If I just return $json, this is what I get:

```
$ perl 1.pl '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
[Wed Mar  7 05:32:19 2018] 1.pl: Use of uninitialized value $json in concatenation (.) or string at 1.pl line 25.
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Results:</h1><div>--><---</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, it looks like my cgi script is not receiving anything from the command line, and the line `my $href = decode_json($json);` is causing the error. Is there a way to send json data on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

```
$ perl 1.pl POSTDATA='{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```